# Firestore read counts of documents size

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the amount of documents in a specific collection as the following :

```
const userCol = db.collection('users').get().then(queryResult => {
   if (queryResult.exists)
       console.log(queryResult.size); // amount of documents
});
```

So as I use `.get()` to read the documents that means that I get `x` **reads** of the amount of documents exists?
If that's true then is there a way to just get the amount of documents without having to read every each one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the amount of **read** will increase only 1 time in the function you wrote. That is, it does not depend on the number of documents. It depend from the number of times use the `get()` function. Each use of the `get()` function means **1 read** count. You will access all documents in the users collection, but the amount of **read** will increase by **1** because you only use `get()` once.

Note:  The definition of `.exist` applies to the document, not the collection.
With the exist command you can poll for the existence of the document, not the collection.

```
const userCol = db.collection('users').get().then(queryResult => {
   console.log(queryResult.size); // amount of documents
});
```

or you can also use `.listDocuments()` property for get documents list in the collection.

```
const userCol = db.collection('users').listDocuments().then(documentsList => {
   console.log(documentsList.length); // amount of documents
});
```

**Both ways will increase the number of 1 reads.**